# Signum or parity of a transposition is $-1$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The definition of signum $\alpha$ is given by
$$sgn(\alpha)=(-1)^{n-t}$$
where $\alpha=\beta_1\dots\beta_t$ a complete factorization of disjoint cycles.

If $\alpha$ is a transposition, then it moves $2$ elements and fixes the remaining $n-2$ elements. Then $t=(n-2)+1=n-1$.So
$$sgn(\alpha)=(-1)^{n-(n-1)}=-1$$

Here I can't understand why $t=(n-2)+1=n-1$

Comment: What is $n$? If it is the number of Elements of the symmetric group $S_n$ your definition may be wrong. Consider $S_4 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and the single cycle $\sigma = (1 2 3) = (1 2) (2 3)$. Then, since the number of transpositions needed to create $\sigma$ is even you should get $sgn(\sigma) = 1 = (-1)^2$ but your formula would yield $sgn(\sigma) = (-1)^{4 - 1} = -1$ which is wrong.

Comment: Note that usually when having a composition into disjoint cycles
$$ \sigma = (m_1 \dots m_{k_1}) (m_{k_1 +1} \dots m_{k_2}) \dots (m_{k_{r-1} + 1} \dots m_{k_r})$$
you calculate the signum as $$sgn(\sigma) = (-1)^{k_r - r},$$ where $k_r$ is the number of elements moved by your permutation and $r$ is the number of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @el_tenedor from the reference book it only stated that $\alpha \in S_n$

Comment: Then, it is not clear to me what $t$ should be. If it is the number of disjoint cycles, as $\alpha = \beta_1 \dots \beta_t$ suggests, for a transposition it should always be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $t$ is the number of disjoint cycles, where every singleton left invariant by the permutation counts as a $1$-cycle. A transposition in $S_n$ has $n-2$ such $1$-cycles and one $2$-cycle, for a total of $t=(n-2)+1=n-1$ disjoint cycles.